# Can't get regex to match in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match just the file extension on a URL to an image.. I've got this regex:

```
(?<=\.)(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|tga|tiff)$
```

I've tested this on several websites and it matches just fine.. but when I try to use it in Java I added an extra \ to escape the . and I don't think I should have to add more than that? but this isn't working:

```
Pattern extensionPat = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|tga|tiff)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher findExtension = extensionPat.matcher(imageURL);
    String extension = findExtension.group();
```

where imageURL is "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"

At a coworker's recommendation I tried escaping the pipes as well into:

```
Pattern extensionPat = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)(jpe?g\\|png\\|gif\\|bmp\\|tga\\|tiff)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I've tried escaping the $, and the <, and nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`findExtension.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) first, otherwise `findExtension.group()` returns nothing.

Comment: Well that was simple... Thanks!

Comment: @JDiPierro, if that solved your problem, please click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it :)

Comment: I will in 8 minutes when it lets me :P